# Parsing character as NaN when reading Excel doesn't work as expected

Tags: python, pandas

My Excel sheet looks like this:

```
   A   B  
1 first second
2  1   -
3  2   -
4  -   5  
5  4   6
```

I try to parse `-` as `NaN` when reading it but this doesn't work:

```py
df = pd.read_excel(excel_file_path, header = 0, na_values = '-')
```

It instead turns `-` to 0. How can I fix it?

Comment: You might run into this problem: https://www.punctuationmatters.com/the-difference-between-a-dash-and-a-minus-sign/. Might want to try `na_values = ['–', '−', '–', '—']`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do it with the following Excel file:

[image]

```py
df = pd.read_excel("file.xlsx", header=0)

df = (
    df
    .applymap(lambda x: str(x).encode("ascii", "ignore").decode("ascii"))
    .replace("", pd.NA)
)
```

```py
print(df)
# Output
  first second
0     1   <NA>
1     2   <NA>
2  <NA>      5
3     4      6
```